# Splitting a very large string in part

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

how to i can split large string in part

i have a very big string and i cant send them

to my php file

i got error : this url is too large

i send them like that

```
Dim bigstr = "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
```

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................................"

sorry i forget
i want to send that string with vbscript
i'm using:

vbs code:

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 phpfile   = "data.php?action=write&data="
    ff = site & ee & str 
    o.open "GET",ff, False
o.send
```

php code :

```
<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];
$data = $_GET['data'];


if ($action == "write"){
unlink("data.txt");
$open = fopen("data.txt", 'a');
fwrite($open, $data);
fclose($open);
}
```

now i want to split that big string into part and send them with loop

or any other solutions

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Perhaps you want to use some kind of web service instead of querystring.

Comment: Can you use POST to send that value? A querystring is limited in size (the exact limits vary), the body of a POST message is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some webbrowsers only support a maximum ammount of characters in a string (your string is about 27.700 characters long). [Here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) is a link to an article about those url-limits on browsers.

So here's one question: Do you really need ALL of that information sent to your PHP-page?
Possible solution: Try to shrink repeating characters (all those A's for instance) to a shorter version. "Ax467" instead of 467 times an "A" in the string. And/Or try to filter out some standard information, or replace it by a shorter string. (27.700 characters is a LOT)